# Complex constraints in Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have the following constraint in a Sequel migratin:

```
constraint(:date_is_1_feb_or_1_aug, 'EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)::INT IN (2,8) AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)::INT = 1')
```

Is there any way to simplify this and use the DSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constraint(:date_is_1_feb_or_1_aug,
   Sequel.extract(:month, :date).cast(Integer)=>[2,8],
   Sequel.extract(:day, :date).cast(Integer)=>1)
```

Comment: Wow! :) Sequel can really do anything?

Comment: Not in this case but in general, can you OR conditions?

Comment: Yes, you can OR conditions: `Sequel.|(cond1, cond2)`